# Script to open a specific Excel file/sheet depending on time/date

Tags: excel, batch-file, vbscript

We have a folder with subfolder for each month, each subfolder contains Excel files for each day. Each Excel file has three sheets with early, late and night shift. What I want is a script that can check what day and time it is at the moment and open the Excel file for it with the sheet for the correct shift. Shift can be specified with the time. For the night shift I need the Excel file from the day before.

The script checks the years (open folder 2015) after checks month (open folder 11 (for example)) then checks time and date (if 7AM or earlier then open night shift one from yesterday, if 7AM or later then open the Excel for today with early shift sheet, if 3PM or later open late shift for correct day). The excel files are named like this: `25.11.2015.xlsx`.
The hierarchy of folders are:

X:\Shifts (here is the VBS script in it)\2015\11\25.11.2015.xlsx

Here is the code I have so far. It's a batch file though I read somewhere it's not possible with batch but I'd better ask here again.
I just don't know where I should add the code to open a specific sheet.
* I didn't write everything on my own, I searched a lot and get specific parts together.

```
@echo off
set day=-1
echo >"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" s=DateAdd("d",%day%,now) : d=weekday(s)
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" WScript.Echo year(s)^& right(100+month(s),2)^& right(100+day(s),2)
for /f %%a in ('cscript /nologo "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"') do set "result=%%a"
del "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"
set "YYYY=%result:~0,4%"
set "MM=%result:~4,2%"
set "DD=%result:~6,2%"
set "data=%dd%.%mm%.%yyyy%"

IF %time:~0,2% GTR 7 (
START "" "Path to file\%DATE:~6,4%\%DATE:~3,2%\%DATE%.xlsm"
)
IF %time:~0,2%== 7 (
START "" "Path to file\%DATE:~6,4%\%DATE:~3,2%\%DATE%.xlsm"
)
IF %time:~0,2% LSS 7 (
START "" "Path to file\%DATE:~6,4%\%DATE:~3,2%\%data%.xlsm"
)
```

Comment: If you've tried for some days, then surely you have some code you can include with your question.  Please do so.

Comment: SO does not provide code writing service. Show us what have you tried so far and we'll be happy to help you with your issues.

Comment: so do you want `vbscript` or `batch`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `vbs`, you can control Excel in order to display the proper sheet.
Not sure you can do that with a batch script but you can execute **.vbs**...
the same as **.bat**

Save the following to **.vbs**
should work, or be close...

```
'Folder - x:\shifts\year\month\dd.mm.yyyy.xlsx
'3 sheets - early, late, night
'Check date/time, open Excel file, set active sheet
'If 7AM or earlier open night shift from yesterday
'If 7AM or later open early shift for today
'If 3PM or later open late shift for today

Dim path   'file path
Dim today  'current date
Dim name   'sheet name  

Dim xclApp  'Excel application
Dim xclWbk  'Excel workbook

'set current date
today = Now()
name = ""

'check shift, set sheet name
If Hour(today) < 7 Then
  'modify date
  today = DateAdd("d", -1, today)
  name = "night"
Else
  If Hour(today) < 15 Then
    name = "early"
  Else
    name = "late"
  End If
End If

'set file path
path = "X:\Shifts\" & Year(today) & "\" & Month(today) & "\" & Day(today) & _
       "." & Month(today) & "." & Year(today) & ".xlsx"

Set xclApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xclApp.Visible = True

Set xclWbk = xclApp.Workbooks.Open(path)
xclWbk.Sheets(name).Activate

Set xclApp = Nothing
Set xclWbk = Nothing
```

Comment: Holy lord your my hero! Gimme a PM so can donate you a beer. It works like a charm! its 100% exactly what i have tried. It also helped to understand how this work. Really my biggest thanks